# Using taglib in a Qt application

Tags: c++, qt, taglib

I'd like to get the length of a media file in a qt application i'm building and so i decided to use taglib. This is the methos that is meant to read the length

```
void loadMetaData(QString file) {
    QByteArray fileName = QFile::encodeName( file );
    const char * encodedName = fileName.constData();
    TagLib::FileRef fileref = TagLib::FileRef( encodedName );
    if (fileref.isNull())
    {
        qDebug() << "Null";
    }
    else
    {
       qDebug() << "Not Null";
    } 
}
```

Problem is fileref is always null for some reason and i can't figure out why......

Comment: My bad! I was testing with ogg theora files, taglib doesn't seem to support them yet.

Tablib should have a better fall back methinks, instead of just returning a null pointer, no?

Comment: Fall back to what? It can't do anything with Theora files, so failing to open them seems the best option to me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the getter [audioProperties()](http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/taglib/api/classTagLib_1_1FileRef.html#5386ca78884d2f870d7171892ef99535) on your FileRef object. The [returned pointer](http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/taglib/api/classTagLib_1_1AudioProperties.html) contains the length of the file in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

TagLib# is able to work with some Theora files. I used it in a project but found it wouldn't work with many Theora videos (I don't think any converted using libtheora 1.1 worked).

```
TagLib.File file = TagLib.File.Create(@"c:\video.ogv");
string height = file.Properties.VideoHeight;
```

This is for the .NET, not C++ though.